# Unable to convert var to List<MyType>

Tags: entity-framework, list, casting, frameworks, entity

can anybody help me whith the following code?

```
        var returned= MyDBContext.MyEntities.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Property1,
            c.Property2,
            c.Property3
        })
        .Where(c => c.Property1.Contains(anyStringParam))
        .OrderBy(c => c.Property1)
        .Take(100)
        .ToList();

         List<MyType>list = returned;
```

I saw some answers in this forum, but i still have problems.

Comment: Have you tried .Select(c => new MyType { ... })?  Does the anonymous type match MyType?

Comment: Hi. The anonymous type matches MyType. "MyEntities" is a collection of MyType. I tried c => new MyType, but a recieve the message: cannot nnitialize type whith a collection initializer becouse it does not implements IEnumerable. thanks

Comment: If MyEntities is a collection of MyType, why are you using Select to project to a new form?  You should be able to remove the Select.

Comment: I would like to be able to specify wich properties i want to load. Without the select can i do this? Thaks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
    var returned= MyDBContext.MyEntities.Select(c => new
    {
        Property1 = c.Property1,
        Property2 = c.Property2,
        Property3 = c.Property3
    })
    .Where(c => c.Property1.Contains(anyStringParam))
    .OrderBy(c => c.Property1)
    .Take(100)
    .AsEnumerable().Select(c => new MyType
    {
        Property1 = c.Property1,
        Property2 = c.Property2,
        Property3 = c.Property3
    }).ToList();
```

The result should be that *returned* is now a *List of MyType*.

Comment: I tried, but i got an exception:                      
The entity or complex type 'LC.SmartTools.Lead.Entity.Contratante' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

LC.SmartTools.Lead.Entity.Contratante is MyType

The code is like this:

var contratantes = DBContexto.Contratantes.Select(c => new Contratante
                {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    Nome_RazaoSocial = c.Nome_RazaoSocial,
                    Tipo = c.Tipo,
                    Ativa = c.Ativa
                })[...]

Is it wrong? THANKS!

Comment: Try the updated solution.  You can't project to an entity type in LINQ-to-Entities, so you have to first project to an anonymous type or POCO class and then project that to your entity type.

Comment: It's working now, and i anderstand the reason.

I really thank you, LP.